# foreach in List<object> in c#

Tags: c#, foreach, properties, generic-list

[[image: Collection of List objects]]

[image: First object from List]

I have List<Object> with 26 rows. I wanted to write foreach to fetch the values. I tried diff ways to get that. no luck. Anyone please help me. Please check the attached images

Comment: What exactly *did* you try? Please write what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck. In particular that avoids to get solutions you already tried that didn´t work for you. Basically all you need is a `foreach(var element in myList) { ... }`

Comment: What did you try and what is "no luck"?  If your question is literally how to write a loop, then you should start with some introductory tutorials on C#.  Things like loops and conditional statements are covered there.

Comment: Why do you even use a `List<object>` and not `List<MfrYearEqpType>`?

Comment: Don't put images in questions, put actual code.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you're asking for so here is some sample code to get you started.  This will create a list that is filled with the string value from each object in the list.

```
List<String> stringList = new List<String>();    
foreach(Object o in ObjectList)
  {
      string s;
      s= o.ToString();
      stringList.Add(s);
  }
```

As it's previously been mentioned, I would take a look at loops and conditional statements to learn more about them/how to use them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good catch @MistyK

Comment: `MfrYearEqpType` seems to be a type, not a list. Apart from this your answer imho doesn´t fit OPs needs, which admitedly aren´t well described.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, I'm really not sure what is being asked.  My original intention was to provide sample code that he could build off.  I edited the answer to make it more general to serve as a tip or sample code for a foreach loop.